# Get class name during class defintion

Tags: python, class, oop

I'm trying to create a an access the name of the class during the class definition.

```py
class Foo:
    print('Creating class Foo')
```

Is there a way to create the referring to the name with explicitly specifying rewriting it?

Something like:

```py
class Foo:
    print('Creating class', __class_name__)
```

`Out[1]: Creating class Foo`

The reason why is that I want to create a logger object that lives inside the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually found a way to do it on Python 3.3+.

It is called a qualified name. [This is the PEP that explains it](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3155/)

This is the code that does it:

```py
class Foo:
    print('Creating class', __qualname__)
```

Comment: `__qualname__` is only documented as an *attribute* of an existing object. I'm not sure how reliable this is.

Answer (score 0):

There is not. If your goal is simply to reduce the number of places where the class name is explicitly mentioned, I would recommend a "private" class attribute that can at least be kept lexically close to the start of the statement, to make it easier to find should you decide to change the name of the class.

```
class Foo:
    _name = 'Foo'

    class_logger = logger.getChild(_name)
```

(This answer predates an edit to the question which removed the use of `__class_name__` in defining a logger as an example.)

Comment: There is actually a way of doing it using `__qualname__`